# Adjective meaning "belonging to a certain category"

Tags: word-choice

I am struggling to think of an adjective suitable in the following example.
(I want to say products that belong to these categories to indicate the product types.)

Products (       ) to custom order, quick shipping or delivery in person.

Can I say "applicable to" or "subject to"?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think the conditions you mention are natural categories. Maybe, "products with special treatment, including....".

Comment: "Categorized" is the adjective that means that, but your explanation is confusing because, in it, it doesn't appear you're looking for an adjective that actually means that but for an adjective or adjectival phrase that means something else, a meaning you fail to make clear enough to offer any kind of suggestion for.

Comment: I mean products that are custom-ordered, have to be shipped quickly, and have to be delivered in person. Is there any adjective that can apply to all of them at once.